# Trade API Poloniex Python 3.5

Tags: python, poloniex

Help me log in to the api poloniex. Below is written my code with which I am trying to log in, but it gives me an error! Python version 3.5. Help me please understand what I'm doing wrong!

```
import urllib
import requests
import json
import time
import hmac,hashlib

api_secret ="111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
api_key="YYYYYYYY-IIIIIIII-PPPPPPPP-LLLLLLLL"

nonce = int(time.time() * 1000)
parms = {"nonce": nonce,"command":'returnBalances'}
post_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(parms)

sign = hmac.new( api_secret.encode(),post_data.encode(), hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
print(sign)
headers = {"Sign":sign,"Key":api_key}
public = requests.post('https://poloniex.com/tradingApi',post_data,headers)

print(public.text)
```

The result of the program is the following:
{"error":"Invalid API key/secret pair."}

Comment: https://github.com/s4w3d0ff/python-poloniex

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import requests
import json
import time
import hmac,hashlib

api_secret ="111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
api_key="YYYYYYYY-IIIIIIII-PPPPPPPP-LLLLLLLL"

nonce = int(time.time() * 1000)
parms = {"nonce": nonce,"command":'returnBalances'}
post_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(parms)

sign = hmac.new( api_secret,post_data, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
print(sign)
headers = {"Sign":sign,"Key":api_key}
ret = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('https://poloniex.com/tradingApi', post_data, headers))
jsonRet = json.loads(ret.read())

print(jsonRet)
```